# Using Silverlight with HTML?

Tags: c#, silverlight, deployment, silverlight-4.0, editor

I usually C++ applications. The only web-application development I've done is writing Java Applets. There it's all pretty simple stuff. Just write the entire applet in Java, and embed  it into an html page with the:

```
<applet></applet> or <object></object>
```

tag.

Now, I am trying to find my way to Silverlight. Now Visual Web-Developer Express or Visual Studio is awesome. It eases all problems, creating a new Silverlight project automatically generates an aspx website and does all the embedding & deployment.

However, I don't want to depend on the IDE. Though I use IDEs quite often, what I hate is *depending* on it. So my questions are,

- **Is it possible to write a silverlight app with a simple programmer's editor?**
- **How do I embed my silverlight XAML code and C-Sharp compiled *.dlls in an HTML file?**
- **Some basic tutorial or documentation for people like me who know absolutely nothing about Silverlight?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How do I embed my silverlight XAML code and C-Sharp compiled *.dlls in an HTML file?**

You can add a silverlight app to a html file simply by using the `<object>` tag (here is an example taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)):

```
<object width="300" height="300"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
</object>
```

**Is it possible to write a silverlight app with a simple programmer's editor?**

It is *possible* to write all of your code for a silverlight app using nothing but notepad, but because of the somewhat verbose nature of XAML, i think this would be a fairly tedious task. If anything, i would suggest you go in the other direction and use [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) to craft your XAML and then Visual Studio for your C# needs - the two IDE's work together very effectively and allow you to easily switch from one to the other with ease.

**Some basic tutorial or documentation for people like me who know absolutely nothing about Silverlight?**

If your looking for good tutorials, head over to the [official silverlight site](http://www.silverlight.net/learn) where you will find lots of tutorials, videos and hands on labs to help you through the learning process.

Here are some other good resources:

- [There were lots of good presentations on Silverlight at MIX10](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10?sort=sequential&direction=desc&term=silverlight)
- Channel9 in general has lots of good vids. [This is their Silverlight section](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/silverlight)
- [A list of great Silverlight resources from SmashingApps](http://www.smashingapps.com/2009/05/02/15-excellent-and-useful-microsoft-silverlight-tutorials-resources.html)
- [Tekpub do a free video course on Silverlight 4](http://tekpub.com/view/ag/1)

Answer (score 0):

The *.xap file generated from compiling a Silverlight application is simply a zip file with a different extension.  You can check out the contents of a `XAP` file by renaming it with a `ZIP` extension, then browsing through it.